# Removed kernel file by accident

Tags: ubuntu, kernel

My boot partition was full so I manually deleted some kernel files in the boot parition. However, I was stupid enough to also delete the files I actually need.

Now when I try to run `sudo apt-get upgrade` I get the following:

```
appliance@zabbix:/boot$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up linux-image-4.4.0-137-generic (4.4.0-137.163) ...
Internal Error: Could not find image (/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-137-generic)
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-137-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-4.4.0-137-generic:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-137-generic depends on linux-image-4.4.0-137-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-4.4.0-137-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-137-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.4.0-137-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-137-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
appliance@zabbix:/boot$
```

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

I already tried: `sudo apt-get install -f` output:

```
appliance@zabbix:/boot$ sudo apt install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up linux-image-4.4.0-137-generic (4.4.0-137.163) ...
Internal Error: Could not find image (/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-137-generic)
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-137-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-4.4.0-137-generic:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-137-generic depends on linux-image-4.4.0-137-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-4.4.0-137-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-137-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.4.0-137-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-137-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

p.s output of `uname -r`:

```
4.4.0-130-generic
```

Comment: What if you tried `# apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-4.4.0-137-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-137-generic`?

Comment: ppliance@zabbix:/usr/lib/zabbix/externalscripts$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-4.4.0-137-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-137-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
E: Internal Error, No file name for linux-image-4.4.0-137-generic:amd64

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed it.

with first running:

```
sudo dpkg -P --force-depends linux-image-4.4.0-137-generic
```

and then:

```
sudo apt upgrade -f
```

now everything works again!

thanks!!